# Handle a dynamic table of structures with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, struct

I have an exercise to write down data to a dynamic table of structures using a function. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct student{ char name[15], surname[20]; int age; };

student * createTab(int tsize)
{
    student *t = new student[tsize];
    return t;
}

void fill(student *t, int tsize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name: "; cin >> t[i].name;
        cout << "Enter a surname: "; cin >> t[i].surname;
        cout << "Enter age: "; cin >> t[i].age;
    }
}

int main()
{
    student *t = createTab(10);
    fill(t, 20);
    cout << t[0].surname << endl;
    cout << t[1].name << endl;
    system("pause");
    delete[]t;
    return 0;
}
```

It works, okay. But here, in `fill()` function I use the index syntax with `student[].name`. I always worked on tables with pointers like that: `*(table+i)` in a for loop. `*(t+i).name` doesn't work. Can I iterate on structure fields using pointers?

P.S - Am I freeing the memory correctly?

And I guess P.S 2 - How is it possible, that when I insert a pointer to a first element of my table to a function, and then I can operate on whole table with indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard defines the subscripting as follows:

> **5.2.1/1** (...) The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

This is why, using a pointer `t` and an index `i`, `*(t+i)` and `t[i]` is the same.  The problem with your code in the context of struct fields, is a question of priority: you may write `(*(t+i)).name` or better `(t+i)->name`, or much clearer, as you did: `t[i].name`.

P.S.: If you allocate a table with `new[...]` you have to free it with `delete[]`.  So yes: it's ok !

Comment: Thanks for a full answer!